# How to create a polynomial function from three inputs in a C function?

Tags: c

The Evaluate function evaluates a polynomial at the given x value and returns the result. The coeff[] array contains the coefficients for the polynomial it should evaluate(which also has the x-min and x-max , and the terms parameter tells it how many terms the polynomial has (how many elements in coeff[] to use). The coeff[] array has the minimum and maximum ranges of the graph which are stored in the first two spaces of the array.

I am really not sure on how to do this.

```
0.0 6.0
25.00 -47.50 25.17 -5.00 0.33
```

so this would be 25 - 47.5x + 25.17x^2 - 5x^3 + 0.33x^4

```
#include "poly.h"

// Then, anything else we need in the implementation file.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int readPoly( int capacity, double coeff[] )
{
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      for (;;) {
        int c;

        if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)
          return i;
        if (!isspace(c)) {
          ungetc(c, stdin);
          break;
      }
      if (scanf("%lf", &coeff[i]) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input");
        exit(INVALID_POLYNOMAIL_STATUS);
      }
   }

   return i;
}

double evaluate( double x, int terms, double coeff[] )
{
  for(int i = 2; i < terms; i++) {

  double equation =
```

Comment: You seem to have omitted a lot of code from `evaluate()`.  We will help you with an honest attempt to solve your problem.  We mostly won't just write the code for you.  Where are you having problems?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't omit anything from evaluate. I am having trouble of how to grab the coefficients from the array and then to use them to create the polynomial.

Comment: You omitted two `}` and one `;` at minimum.  There's more missing than that, though.  You've not really shown the input format (treat the data like you would/did treat code — add a line `<-- language: lang-none -->` unindented on a line on its own before the data to avoid any highlighting on it (but that's advanced icing on the cake).  You mention `x-min` and `x-max` but don't show where they come from.  You don't explain what number you use to identify the number of coefficients.  Judging from your explanation of the quartic, the number will be either `4` or `5`.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ It isn't clear whether the `0.0` and `6.0` are the outer limits on the range of `x` and you're meant to evaluate the polynomial at some number of values between (and including) those limits.  It isn't clear how many such evaluations are required?  (Seven might be reasonable, at 0, 1, … 5, 6; or maybe you're meant to 10 evaluations per unit, at 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, …, 5.9, 6.0; or something else).  Note that if you don't know what the expected output is, we can't help you — we have to rely on you to tell us what is expected.

Comment: See Wikipedia on [Horner's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) — or method, or various other names.

Comment: I am supposed to get 99 values between 0 and 6(0 and 6 for that specific example).

Comment: OK; pity you didn't mention that in the question. Should that be x-values 0 and 6 and 97 other values, or should it exclude either or both of the end points?  You need different formulae to generate the correct set of x-values depending on the exact output desired.  Of course, I'm assuming that you mean a uniformly distributed set of x-values; one could also generate a sequence of random numbers between 0 and 6 and claim "that's what was asked for".  What are your thoughts about calculating the value of the polynomial if `x` is `2.5`?  How do you calculate it manually?  Programmatically?

Comment: Calculating it manually is basic math but the trouble I am having is how to construct the polynomial in the first place. In total, it should be 101 values including the end points

Comment: FWIW: I was under-caffeinated when I typed `<-- … -->`; that should be `<!-- language: lang-none -->` with an exclamation mark after the `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite loop in your input function seems to be designed to skip over white space before you try reading a number with `scanf("%lf", &coeff[i])`.  That's moderately pointless — the numeric formats all skip leading white space, including newlines, automatically.  Only three format specifiers do not skip white space; they are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.

You probably need to capture the return value from `scanf()` so that you can distinguish between EOF and bogus inputs:

```
int rc;
int i = 0;
while (i < capacity && (rc = scanf("%lf", &coeff[i])) == 1)
    i++;

if (i == capacity)
{
    /* Too many values; remainder ignored */
}
else if (rc == 0)
{
    /* Report format error */
}
else if (rc == EOF && i < 4)
{
    /* Insufficient valid data */
    /* Needed x-min, x-max, coeff[0] (constant term) and coeff[1] (linear term */
}
return i;
```

The `evaluate()` function evaluates the polynomial at a given value of *x*.  The best process is known as [Horner's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) or Horner's Method.  Given the input format with the constant term read before the *x* term and the *x*² term, you need to work backwards from the highest coefficient.

```
double evaluate(double x, int terms, double coeff[])
{
    double r = coeff[terms - 1];
    int i = terms - 1;
    while (i > 0)
        r = (r * x) + coeff[--i];
    return r;
}
```

The function calling the `evaluate()` function needs arguments:

```
x_min   — starting value
x_max   — ending value
x_steps — number of values to print (101 in this case)
n_coeff — number of coefficients
coeff   — the array of coefficients
```

It could become:

```
static void print_values(double x_min, double x_max, int x_steps, int n_coeff, double coeff[n_coeff])
{
    const char *pad = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < x_steps; i++)
    {
        double x = (x_max - x_min) * i / (x_steps - 1) + x_min;
        double r = evaluate(x, n_coeff, coeff);
        printf("%s%3d: P(%5.3f) = %10.6f", pad, i, x, r);
        if (i % 3 == 2)
            pad = "\n";
        else
            pad = "; ";
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

And the `main()` function could become:

```
enum { MAX_COEFF = 10 };

int main(void)
{
    double coeff[MAX_COEFF];

    int n_coeff = readPoly(MAX_COEFF, coeff);
    double x_min = coeff[0];
    double x_max = coeff[1];
    int n_values = 101;
    print_values(x_min, x_max, n_values, n_coeff - 2, &coeff[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

And, for the given data:

```
0.0 6.0
25.00 -47.50 25.17 -5.00 0.33
```

the generated output is:

```
  0: P(0.000) =  25.000000;   1: P(0.060) =  22.239536;   2: P(0.120) =  19.653876
  3: P(0.180) =  17.236694;   4: P(0.240) =  14.981767;   5: P(0.300) =  12.882973
  6: P(0.360) =  10.934295;   7: P(0.420) =   9.129817;   8: P(0.480) =   7.463726
  9: P(0.540) =   5.930312;  10: P(0.600) =   4.523968;  11: P(0.660) =   3.239189
 12: P(0.720) =   2.070572;  13: P(0.780) =   1.012818;  14: P(0.840) =   0.060730
 15: P(0.900) =  -0.790787;  16: P(0.960) =  -1.546724;  17: P(1.020) =  -2.211969
 18: P(1.080) =  -2.791311;  19: P(1.140) =  -3.289431;  20: P(1.200) =  -3.710912
 21: P(1.260) =  -4.060232;  22: P(1.320) =  -4.341766;  23: P(1.380) =  -4.559788
 24: P(1.440) =  -4.718468;  25: P(1.500) =  -4.821875;  26: P(1.560) =  -4.873973
 27: P(1.620) =  -4.878625;  28: P(1.680) =  -4.839591;  29: P(1.740) =  -4.760529
 30: P(1.800) =  -4.644992;  31: P(1.860) =  -4.496433;  32: P(1.920) =  -4.318202
 33: P(1.980) =  -4.113545;  34: P(2.040) =  -3.885606;  35: P(2.100) =  -3.637427
 36: P(2.160) =  -3.371946;  37: P(2.220) =  -3.092000;  38: P(2.280) =  -2.800322
 39: P(2.340) =  -2.499544;  40: P(2.400) =  -2.192192;  41: P(2.460) =  -1.880693
 42: P(2.520) =  -1.567371;  43: P(2.580) =  -1.254444;  44: P(2.640) =  -0.944031
 45: P(2.700) =  -0.638147;  46: P(2.760) =  -0.338704;  47: P(2.820) =  -0.047512
 48: P(2.880) =   0.233722;  49: P(2.940) =   0.503393;  50: P(3.000) =   0.760000
 51: P(3.060) =   1.002144;  52: P(3.120) =   1.228527;  53: P(3.180) =   1.437957
 54: P(3.240) =   1.629342;  55: P(3.300) =   1.801693;  56: P(3.360) =   1.954124
 57: P(3.420) =   2.085853;  58: P(3.480) =   2.196198;  59: P(3.540) =   2.284582
 60: P(3.600) =   2.350528;  61: P(3.660) =   2.393665;  62: P(3.720) =   2.413722
 63: P(3.780) =   2.410532;  64: P(3.840) =   2.384029;  65: P(3.900) =   2.334253
 66: P(3.960) =   2.261343;  67: P(4.020) =   2.165542;  68: P(4.080) =   2.047197
 69: P(4.140) =   1.906755;  70: P(4.200) =   1.744768;  71: P(4.260) =   1.561889
 72: P(4.320) =   1.358875;  73: P(4.380) =   1.136585;  74: P(4.440) =   0.895980
 75: P(4.500) =   0.638125;  76: P(4.560) =   0.364186;  77: P(4.620) =   0.075434
 78: P(4.680) =  -0.226760;  79: P(4.740) =  -0.540922;  80: P(4.800) =  -0.865472
 81: P(4.860) =  -1.198732;  82: P(4.920) =  -1.538918;  83: P(4.980) =  -1.884145
 84: P(5.040) =  -2.232425;  85: P(5.100) =  -2.581667;  86: P(5.160) =  -2.929678
 87: P(5.220) =  -3.274162;  88: P(5.280) =  -3.612720;  89: P(5.340) =  -3.942852
 90: P(5.400) =  -4.261952;  91: P(5.460) =  -4.567315;  92: P(5.520) =  -4.856131
 93: P(5.580) =  -5.125488;  94: P(5.640) =  -5.372373;  95: P(5.700) =  -5.593667
 96: P(5.760) =  -5.786151;  97: P(5.820) =  -5.946503;  98: P(5.880) =  -6.071297
 99: P(5.940) =  -6.157006; 100: P(6.000) =  -6.200000
```

The code doesn't print the polynomial for validation; it should.  Clearly, the output when `x` is 0 should be `25` and it is, which gives some reassurance.  In the limit, the 0.33x^4 term should dominate, so the result tends towards infinity as x increases towards infinity.  The final 0 of the polynomial given is at an `x` value just less than 7.

Comment: To create the polynomal in evaluate(), can't you use "equation = equation + coeff[i] * pow(x, terms);" with a for loop?

Comment: I could, but it wouldn’t be as good as using Horner’s Rule. All else apart, it would be slower. This method uses _n_ multiplies and _n_ additions.